# XSLT not working with my XML

Tags: html, xml, xcode, xslt, xhtml

Hi my XSL doesn't seem to be working with my XML. I can't seem to figure out the problem even though my code is quite simple. My XML sheet seems to transform into just raw Data when i link to the XSL spreadsheet and open the document.

My XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/"> 
<html>
<head>
  <title>Room Information</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Room information</h1>
   <table border="1">
   <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th>TITLE</th>
    <th>ACCOMODATION</th>
    <th>COST</th>
    <th>LEVEL</th>
    <th>VIEW</th>
    <th>ENSUITE</th>
    <th>MAID_SERVICE</th>
    <th>ROOM_SERVICE</th>
    <th>LAUNDRY_SHOOT</th>
    <th>ROOM_IMAGE</th>
    <th>PAST_CUSTOMERS</th>
   </tr>
<xsl:for-each select="ROOMS/ROOM">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="ACCOMODATION"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="COST"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="LEVEL"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="VIEW"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="ENSUITE"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="MAID_SERVICE"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="ROOM_SERVICE"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="LAUNDRY_SHOOT"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="ROOM_IMAGE"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="PAST_CUSTOMERS"/></td>
            </tr>

</xsl:for-each>
```

This is my XML (The DTD can just be ignored)

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSL/RoomsXSL.xsl"?>

<!DOCTYPE ROOMS [
<!ELEMENT ROOM (TITLE+,ACCOMODATION,COST,LEVEL+,VIEW,ENSUITE,MAID_SERVICE,ROOM_SERVICE,LAUNDRY_SHOOT,ROOM_IMAGE+,PAST_CUSTOMERS+)>
<!ELEMENT TITLE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ACCOMODATION (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT COST (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT LEVEL (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT VIEW (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ENSUITE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT MAID_SERVICE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ROOM_SERVICE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT LAUNDRY_SHOOT (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ROOM_IMAGE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT PAST_CUSIMERS (#PCDATA)>

<!ENTITY writer "Dylan Weiss">
<!ENTITY copyright "Horizon BnB">
]>

<ROOMS>
  <ROOM id="01">
    <TITLE>Top Floor 1</TITLE>
    <ACCOMODATION>Accomodates 2 people</ACCOMODATION>
    <COST>$700 a week.$120 every day over a week</COST>
    <LEVEL>Top floor</LEVEL>
    <VIEW>Includes panoramic View</VIEW>
    <ENSUITE>Has ensuite</ENSUITE>
    <MAID_SERVICE>Maid service included</MAID_SERVICE>
    <ROOM_SERVICE>Includes room service</ROOM_SERVICE>
    <LAUNDRY_SHOOT>Includes laundry shoot</LAUNDRY_SHOOT>
    <ROOM_IMAGE>Images/LuxuryRoom1.jpg</ROOM_IMAGE>
    <PAST_CUSTOMERS>WWW.Horizon/PastCustomers.com</PAST_CUSTOMERS>
  </ROOM>

  <ROOM id="02">
    <TITLE>Bottom floor 1</TITLE>
    <ACCOMODATION>Accomodates 2 people</ACCOMODATION>
    <COST>$500 a week.$100 every day over a week</COST>
    <LEVEL>Ground floor</LEVEL>
    <VIEW>Includes a courtyard</VIEW>
    <ENSUITE>Has ensuite</ENSUITE>
    <MAID_SERVICE>Maid service included</MAID_SERVICE>
    <ROOM_SERVICE>Includes room service</ROOM_SERVICE>
    <LAUNDRY_SHOOT>No laundry shoot</LAUNDRY_SHOOT>
    <ROOM_IMAGE>Images/LuxuryRoom1.jpg</ROOM_IMAGE>
    <PAST_CUSTOMERS>WWW.Horizon/PastCustomers.com</PAST_CUSTOMERS>
  </ROOM>

  <ROOM id="03">
    <TITLE>Bottom floor 2</TITLE>
    <ACCOMODATION>Accomodates 4 people</ACCOMODATION>
    <COST>$800 a week.$120 every day over a week</COST>
    <LEVEL>Ground floor</LEVEL>
    <VIEW>Includes a courtyard</VIEW>
    <ENSUITE>Has ensuite</ENSUITE>
    <MAID_SERVICE>Maid service included</MAID_SERVICE>
    <ROOM_SERVICE>Includes room service</ROOM_SERVICE>
    <LAUNDRY_SHOOT>No laundry shoot</LAUNDRY_SHOOT>
    <ROOM_IMAGE>Images/LuxuryRoom1.jpg</ROOM_IMAGE>
    <PAST_CUSTOMERS>WWW.Horizon/PastCustomers.com</PAST_CUSTOMERS>
  </ROOM>
</ROOMS>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using matching templates instead of your for-each: Your root template will pull the matching `ROOMS` template which in turn will pull the matching `ROOM`.

`<xsl:apply-template />` will take care to fetch the matching template at the desired position.

If you ever need to hide an element, just declare an empty template: `<xsl:template match="ROOM" />`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Room Information</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Room information</h1>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>TITLE</th>
                        <th>ACCOMODATION</th>
                        <th>COST</th>
                        <th>LEVEL</th>
                        <th>VIEW</th>
                        <th>ENSUITE</th>
                        <th>MAID_SERVICE</th>
                        <th>ROOM_SERVICE</th>
                        <th>LAUNDRY_SHOOT</th>
                        <th>ROOM_IMAGE</th>
                        <th>PAST_CUSTOMERS</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROOMS">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROOM">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ACCOMODATION"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="COST"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="LEVEL"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="VIEW"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ENSUITE"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="MAID_SERVICE"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ROOM_SERVICE"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="LAUNDRY_SHOOT"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ROOM_IMAGE"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="PAST_CUSTOMERS"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hmmmm it still doesn't seem to work. The XML understands i have linked the XSL but doesn't seem to accept the changes to format it into a table.

Comment: Runs just fine in IE on my machine. Your sample Xsl is missing the very first `<`, but I assume that's just a copy-paste error.